# how to avoid creating a new line when hitting return in auto complete mode

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

auto-complete in my emacs works great. But there is one annoyance. If I have finished a word correctly like "abc", but in the mean time there is another matching word called "abcd". The menu showed two options with the first one "abc" selected as default. At this time, if I hit RET, it will select "abc" as well as creating a new line. This is annoying. I want it to be just complete the selection when I hit RET. And create a new line only if I hit RET again. Is there a way to set up auto-complete to behave like that

Comment: What completion you use? I use `ivy` which does not make a newline when you choose an already completed word.

Comment: @manandearth I use auto-complete package, can ivy do code completion as well?

Comment: I use Ivy and Elpy and Anaconda, the answer is yes.

Comment: @manandearth would you mind sharing the set up.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/manandearth/d.emacs/blob/master/init.org) ... remember it is work in progress.